# How to display the values entered by user and make decisions based on it?

Tags: ios, swift

For example, if user enters 4 and 4 in a row, I like to see Value is same and value entered is 4
and if user enters  4 and 5 in a row, I like to see Values are different and values entered are 4,5.
In my code `userValue` is something which will be entered by the user and keeps on changing

```
var userValue:Int!
var outputValue:Int! = userValue

if (outputValue == userValue)
{
  print("Value is same and value entered is " + String(userValue))
}
else
{
    print("Values are different and values entered are ")
}
```

How do I display the values that user enters every time one after another and make decisions based on it as above?

Comment: coder221 were you want to get the input - From text field

Comment: @Arun, yes but it takes integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let fullName : String = "A,B"
let fullNameArr : [String] = fullName.components(separatedBy: ",")

var firstName : String = fullNameArr[0]
var lastName : String = fullNameArr[1]

if (firstName == lastName)
{
 print("Value is same and value entered is " + String(userValue))
}
else
{
   print("Values are different and values entered are ")
}
```

Try this may help.I didnt check

Comment: TextField returns only String. You can subclass TextField and implement your own class to get integers directly by type casting.